# SystemVerilog Arrays

Tags: multidimensional-array, system-verilog

Is this array declaration valid?

```
bit[31:0] shadow_mem[bit[31:0]];
```

But what does this mean?

We usually declare it as

```
bit[31:0] shadow_mem[31:0];
```

Are the two declarations different?
What is the purpose of declaring the second dimension with bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an associative array declaration with an index type of `bit [31:0]` I.e. an array with a 32-bit address.  It’s not a 32-element array.